# How can you capture the offending line from TextFieldParser when it throws an error?

Tags: c#, parsing, text, error-handling

I'm using the `TextFieldParser` class to read CSV files. It has two methods for ingesting lines of data: `ReadFields()` and `ReadLine()`. As you might imagine the former treats the data as columnar, separated by pre-set delimiters and the latter reads the raw data. I'm using the former, in code like this:

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(newestFile.FullName))
{
    parser.Delimiters = ","
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> result = parser.ReadFields().ToList();
            // do something 
        }
        catch(MalformedLineException ex)
        {
            // log error to record line where it happened
        }   
    }
}
```

The catch for `MalformedLineException` is there to ensure the thing doesn't fall over if it meets a line that doesn't meet the parsing criteria - it might have additional quotes within a field, for example - it registers this and then moves on to the next line without bringing the whole thing to a halt.

What I'd really like to do in the catch block, though, is log the actual text of the line along with the line number to make it a bit easier to find out what the problem was. But I have no idea how I can get it: `ReadFields` appears to move on to the next line even when it errors, and if I call `ReadLine` in the catch block it also moves on to the next line, meaning lines get skipped. It does not appear to be part of the exception thrown, or available via the object when `ReadFields` fails.

Is there a way to use the `TextFieldParser` to capture this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't actually intend to answer my own question, but this turned out to be very easy: there are other methods on the object to do just this: `ErrorLine` and `ErrorLineNumber`.

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(newestFile.FullName))
{
    parser.Delimiters = ","
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> result = parser.ReadFields().ToList();
            // do something 
        }
        catch(MalformedLineException ex)
        {
            int errorLine = parser.ErrorLineNumber;
            string originalData =  parser.ErrorLine;
            // log them
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I was confused with you statement "But I have no idea how I can get it: ReadFields appears to move on to the next line even when it errors, " thinking that once it errors, it is not continuing the while loop and trying to figure out whats wrong with this...otherwise it was a simple one